# regex: Matching a javascript mime type in content-type http header

Tags: javascript, php, regex, http

Looking for some way, I can verify the javascript content-type,

I have made

```
if(preg_match('/(text|application)\/javascript/i',$header){ #code ...
```

but this won't work all the cases because some servers reply with **application/x-javascript**

and my way verify **application/javascript** and **text/javascript**.

Comment: well if they all include *javascript* check for that

Comment: Ohh, I could implement if(preg_match('/.*javascript/i',$header){ #code ... \n and it would work. But i want a more specific way. However thanks @Dagon

Comment: there are crazier plans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current answer is:

```
(text|application)\/(x-)?javascript
```

Will match `x-javascript` part too. Thats very small and basic change, I recommend you to study a bit more about regexp.
And you might find site [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) quite useful for your experiments.